# Find all common elements of two sorted arrays use binary search

Tags: java, arrays, binary

I've started to learn Java, so I have some stupid questions.
I want to find all common elements of two sorted arrays, use binary search, below is my code.
It runs without right result.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CommonElements{
    public static void commonElements(int[] iArr1, int[] iArr2) {
        Arrays.sort(iArr1);
        Arrays.sort(iArr2);
        int index2 = 0, index1 = 0;
        int left1 = 0, right1 = (iArr1.length)-1;

        while (index2 < iArr2.length && index1 < iArr1.length) {
            while (left1 <= right1) {
                int mid1 = (left1 + right1)/2;
                if (iArr2[index2] == iArr1[mid1]) {
                    System.out.print(iArr1[mid1] + " ");
                    index2++;
                } else if (iArr2[index2] > iArr1[mid1])
                    left1 = mid1 + 1;
                else right1 = mid1 - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] iArr1 = {6,-3,9,-1,0,0,8};
        int[] iArr2 = {-7,6,-3,-5};
        commonElements(iArr1,iArr2);
        System.out.println("END");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why Binary Search the array when you can just use two pointers to find the common elements in two sorted arrays? You can increment the pointer that points to the smaller value of the two pointers in each iteration, and if two values are equal then that means the element is common in both arrays, now increment both pointers and print the common element.

```
    public static void commonElements(int[] iArr1, int[] iArr2) {
        Arrays.sort(iArr1);
        Arrays.sort(iArr2);
        int index2 = 0, index1 = 0;

        while (index2 < iArr2.length && index1 < iArr1.length) {
            if (iArr2[index2] < iArr1[index1]) {
                index2++;
            } else if (iArr2[index2] > iArr1[index1]) {
                index1++;
            } else {
                System.out.print(iArr1[index1] + " ");
                index1++;
                index2++;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Input:**

iArr1 => [-3,-1,0,0,6,8,9],
iArr2 => [-7,-5,-3,6]

**Output:**
-3 6

#### Edit:

If Binary Search is required then you can edit your code to something like this to make it not run into an infinite loop (I've marked the changes using comments):

```
    public static void commonElements(int[] iArr1, int[] iArr2) {
        Arrays.sort(iArr1);
        Arrays.sort(iArr2);
        int index2 = 0, index1 = 0;

        while (index2 < iArr2.length && index1 < iArr1.length) {
            int left1 = 0, right1 = (iArr1.length)-1; // 1) Reinitialize left1 and right1 in each iteration of iArr2.

            while (left1 <= right1) {
                int mid1 = (left1 + right1)/2;
                if (iArr2[index2] == iArr1[mid1]) {
                    System.out.print(iArr1[mid1] + " ");
                    break; // 2) Break out of the binary search when you've found the common element.
                } else if (iArr2[index2] > iArr1[mid1])
                    left1 = mid1 + 1;
                else right1 = mid1 - 1;
            }

            index2++; // 3) Move to next item of iArr2.
        }
    }
```

Comment: This work requires using binary search, and 2 arrays is my example, you can change it to any length and value.

Comment: @QuangMinh I've edited the answer to use binary search

Comment: @QuangMinh Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer if it was useful.

Comment: What is the runtime of the binary search implementation?